# Conditions for maximum power transfer in an AC circuit

Tags: ac, impedance-matching

So, if we're given the circuit below:
[image]

Known values are:
\$E_g=35 \ kV\$
\$f=685 \ kHz\$
\$\underline{Z}_g=150 \ \Omega\$
\$\underline{Z}_p=(200-j300) \ \Omega\$

We have to calculate \$L\$ and \$C\$ to maximize the power transfer to the load \$\underline{Z}_p\$. 
Aside from the impedance matching condition: \$Z_p=Z_g^*\$, is there anything else that can help me solve this circuit?

Comment: Quote "maximum power transfer occurs when the load impedance is equal to the complex conjugate of the source impedance."

Comment: The matching condition is all you need to solve your circuit.

Comment: @JIm Dearden, DavideM: that helps only if you have freedom to match imaginary **and** real parts of the impedances. In this case, however, \$Re(Z_g) = 150\Omega\$ and \$Re(Z_p)=200\Omega\$ are given and real impedance parts may not become equal and there is still a maximum under those conditions.

Comment: Oh yes you have to match both real and imaginary, but you you have two degrees of freedom L and C. Why not to use them?

Comment: Bedtime hint: Aside from the impedance matching condition: \$Z_p=Z_g^*\$  you may find usefull series/parallel conversion of impedances.

Comment: Why not calculate this yourself by calculating \$V_g\$ and \$I_g\$ in terms of \$X_L\$ and \$X_C\$ and then doing \$\max(V_g\cdot I_g^*)\$ or \$\max(\operatorname{Re}(V_g\cdot I_g^*))\$ as applicable?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a bit late to the party, but this question does not have a correct answer yet.

The trick is to first calculate a reactance to be put in parallel with the load, such that the resulting impedance has a real part equal to 150 ohm. This happens when a parallel reactance of -2000 ohm is chosen. The imaginary part of the resulting impedance will then be -274 ohm, which can be compensated by a positive reactance of 274 ohm.

A capacitor of 116 pF has a reactance of -2000 ohm at 685 kHz, an inductor of 63.7 uH will provide the reactance of 274 ohm.

The result is the following network:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6hjsu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course the die hard RF guys would have used a Smith chart :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is wrong as carloc has said with the parallel/serial LC connection.

---

\$Z_p\$ is the load. So the source is everything else (not just \$Z_g\$).

When the source is fixed, and the load is variable, then "maximum power transfer occurs when the load impedance is equal to the complex conjugate of the source impedance."

But in this case, the load \$Z_p\$ is fixed, while the source is variable. For this circuit, I think maximum power to \$Z_p\$ occurs when:

- Maximize source Thevinin equivalent voltage.
  Set \$ C = 0 \$
- Minimum real source resistance.
  \$ Zg = 150\Omega \$ is already fixed cannot be reduced.
- Equal and opposite source imaginary reactance to the load.
  \$ Im\{Z_s\} = -Im\{Z_p\} = j300 \$
  From this you can calculate the inductance of L.

These rules may not work if the source circuit elements are arranged differently.

Comment: Yours is not maximum, you still have to match real parts. Maybe C=0 is not  a great idea, you just throw away  one degree of freedom to work on the circuit.

Comment: @carloc you have the common misconception of the maximum power theorem.

Comment: Really? I belive you've never seen a matching network before. Maximum power transfer means:  Zp load impedance (fixed) shall be transformed by L/C adapter to match Zg* source impedance conjugate (fixed too). Since L/C is not dissipative this also accomplish maximum power.

Comment: @carloc you are correct.