# Conditions for maximum power transfer in an AC circuit answer

Tags: ac, passive-networks, impedance-matching

This question has no satisfactory answers yet so i just tried

> [Conditions for maximum power transfer in an AC circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/256079/conditions-for-maximum-power-transfer-in-an-ac-circuit)

[image]

> Now i stuck at the equation 1 and 2 and don't know how to solve them further ?
>   Also is my logic correct ?
>    Please help me

Comment: Why do not you solve them?, \$\omega\$ is known and you have two equations with two variables!.

Comment: @Hazem that i don't know how to simplfy it further ? please help me

Comment: If equation 1 was 3/2 times bigger then simplification is clearly obvious - this is a math question and not an EE one. I think eq 1 and 2 are correct and your approach is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your all-in-one approach is formally correct, as you already found out at your expenses, it practically takes you nowhere. You soon get lost into some hard boring math.

A much better way is to divide the problem in smaller easy to cope sub-sets.

But even before what you need is to get the right rig from your toolbox.

> In this case  parallel-series resistance-reactance conversion is the the right way to do it.
>
> [image: schematic]
>
> It can be easily proven that at one frequency, given \$Q=\frac{R_\text{p}}{X_\text{p}}=\frac{X_\text{s}}{R_\text{s}}\$ it holds true that
>   $$R_\text{s}=R_\text{p}\,\frac{1}{Q^2+1}\quad\quad X_\text{s}=X_\text{p}\,\frac{Q^2}{Q^2+1}=Q\,R_\text{s}$$
>
> on a par with
>   $$R_\text{p}=R_\text{s}(Q^2+1)\quad\quad
> X_\text{p}=X_\text{s}\,\frac{Q^2+1}{Q^2}=\frac{R_\text{p}}{Q}$$

So, it's now time to try apply the above to your problem:
[image]

1) Transform the given load to parallel
$$Q=\frac{X_\text{s}}{R_\text{s}}=\frac{300\,\Omega}{200\,\Omega}=1.5$$
$$R_\text{p}=R_\text{s}\,(Q^2+1)=200\times(1.5^2+1)=650\,\Omega$$
$$X_\text{p}=\frac{R_\text{p}}{Q}=\frac{650\Omega}{1.5}=433.3\,\Omega$$
[image]

2) Now we shall find Q needed to match 650Ω resistance to 150Ω source once ZL and XC toghether will be reverted to series.
$$R_\text{s}=R_\text{p}\,\frac{1}{Q^2+1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad
Q=\sqrt{\frac{R_\text{p}}{R_\text{s}}-1}=\sqrt{\frac{650\,\Omega}{150\,\Omega}-1}=1.826$$

3) To achieve this we need a total parallel reactance as
$$Q=\frac{R_\text{p}}{X_\text{p}}\quad\Rightarrow\quad X_\text{p}=\frac{R_\text{p}}{Q}=\frac{650\,\Omega}{1.826}=356\,\Omega$$
which shall be achieved by parallelling unknown XC and -j433Ω, so
$$X_\text{c}=\frac{433.3\,\Omega\times 356\,\Omega}{433.3\,\Omega - 356\,\Omega}=1995\,\Omega$$
[image]

> in short \$X_\text{c}=1995\,\Omega\$

4) Back to series, everything needed is out there, we already know Q=1.826 and Rs=150Ω, so we just convert reactance
$$Q=\frac{X_\text{s}}{R_\text{s}}\quad\Rightarrow\quad X_\text{s}=Q\,R_\text{s}=1.826\times 150\,\Omega=274\,\Omega$$
[image]

5) Now it's really done, quite obviously

> XL=274ohm 
>   too, so to cancel series reactances.

6) Finally I'd rather go through a numerical check of our results

[image]

which, besides some rounding error, matches pretty well your specifications.

As you see, this *dividi et impera* approach turns a huge complex equation into just a few elementary operations.

Comment: Good explanation and the shorter *motus operandi* is solve for conjugate match